# Control created in Custom Layout Control returns Null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, c1richtextbox

I am trying to create my own custom layout control, so I created a UserControl like the following:

```
public partial class KTopContentBottomLayout : UserControl
{
    Orientation _Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    public Orientation Orientation { get { return this._Orientation; } set { this._Orientation = value;  } }

    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LayoutRoot.Children;
        }
    }

    public KTopContentBottomLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateProperLayout();
    }
    //Some other code that creates the layouts
}
```

Then in my MainPage.xaml that uses this control:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <local:KTopContentBottomLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <local:KTopContentBottomLayout.Children>
            <StackPanel>
                <c1:C1RichTextBoxToolbar  RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=MyRichTextBox}"/>
            </StackPanel>
                <c1:C1RichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextBox" ReturnMode="HardLineBreak" />
        </local:KTopContentBottomLayout.Children>
    </local:KTopContentBottomLayout>
</Grid>
```

So far everything compile fine and display properly.
But when I try to use the control in Loaded event:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyRichTextBox.GotFocus += MyRichTextBox_GotFocus;
    this.MyRichTextBox.LostFocus += MyRichTextBox_LostFocus;
}
```

The `MyRichTextBox` object is returns null...

I tried to place the control out of my custom layout control and is working fine.  So what did I done wrong?

**EDIT:**

I notice if I access the `MyRichTextBox` through the `KTopContentBottomLayout`, I could access the `MyRichTextBox` properly.

i.e Create a property/Access by using Children.First() etc.

But I don't understand why if I access in `MainPage.xaml` directly to the `MyRichTextBox` will give me null.

If I replace `KTopContentBottomLayout` as `Grid/StackPanel`, they can access `MyRichTextBox` directly, but what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `MyRichTextBox` inside some sort of `Panel` (`StackPanel`, `Grid`, etc).

Edit: Actually, why isn't it in the `StackPanel` to begin with? If you want some hierarchy, do an outer `StackPanel` with a nested `StackPanel` for the toolbar.

Another Edit: I can't copy it into a project right now to try it, but is the line: `this.LayoutRoot.Children` returning what you think it does?

Comment: Like I said, it works in other place once outside my layout control. Of course I would use StackPanel or Grid to do the same thing, but this layout control I am creating is just to provide a standard layout for my testing.

Comment: Just noticed, are you trying to access `MyRichTextBox` from a MainPage.xaml.cs instead of KTopContentBottomLayout? It isn't defined in MainPage, it's in the usercontrol.

Comment: Yeah, but if I do the same thing to let the MyRichTextBox defined inside a StackPanel it will still work... And yes, this.LayoutRoot.Children does returns what I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Are you saying that if you put the richtextbox in the stack panel, it works? If so, problem solved.

Comment: What I mean is if I don't use my own layout control, but using Stack/Grid it will work.  The problem here is when ever I creates 'Controls' that inside my Custom Layout Control, the 'Controls' will returns null...

Comment: Can you add `x:Name="MyRichTextBoxToolbar"` to your toolbar and see if it is null, too?